# How do I nudge geom text labels to the right with a chart with ggplotly?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I'd like to set the text on each of the columns in ggplot and they're bunching up altogether

this is my code

```
set.seed(1)
gg <-
  iris[sample(300, 50), ] %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Species, Sepal.Length, label = Sepal.Length, fill = as.factor(Sepal.Width > 3))) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge2") +
  geom_text(position=position_dodge(width = .7), 
            vjust=-0.25) 
  
ggplotly(gg)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I would suggest using same position style in `geom_col()` and `geom_text()`:

```
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(1)
#Plot
gg <-
  iris[sample(300, 50), ] %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Species, Sepal.Length, label = Sepal.Length, fill = as.factor(Sepal.Width > 3))) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge2(0.9)) +
  geom_text(position=position_dodge2(width = .9), 
            vjust=-0.5) 
#Transform
ggplotly(gg)
```

Output:

[image]

With shared data, try this, you have to format the date to have dodged labels:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
#Code
gg <- df %>% 
  mutate(first_month=factor(format(first_month,'%b-%m'),
                            levels = unique(format(first_month,'%b-%m')),
                            ordered = T)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=first_month, y=customers,
             label = customers, fill = plan_id,group=plan_id)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity',position = 'dodge')+
  geom_text(aes(group=plan_id),position = position_dodge(0.9),vjust = -0.5)
#Plot 2
ggplotly(gg)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: @Cauder Try re starting `R` and only load `ggplot2` and `plotly`. Also first test on the dumy data you created!

Comment: @Cauder There must be the data, can you share a sample of it using `dput()`?

Comment: @Cauder Checking now!

Comment: @Cauder I have added an update, hoping that helps you!

Comment: Why does the first monthvalue need to be a factor? That's interesting

Comment: @Cauder Otherwise, you have plenty of dates, and that is why the labels can not be dodged!